# How can I compile a ServiceDescription so that its import statements are inlined?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wsdl

I'm trying to programmatically read wsdl files in C#. I'm struggling with the import statement in wsdl's. The .net classes 'ServiceDescription' and 'DiscoveryClientProtocol' allow me to read in a wsdl file and all the wsdl files that it imports, but these are returned as separate ServiceDescriptions. Ideally I'd like a single ServiceDescription in which all the imports have been 'inlined'/'flattened'. For schemas there is a nice XmlSchemaSet.Compile method, but I haven't found the web service analogue of that.

Comment: Hi, I have some issue with you, do you have any update solutions?